# is important the diagram of database in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, diagrams

I have a database with the tables, FK and so on. Also I have created a diagram. When I am adding tables into the diagram, the tables show the relationships between other tables.

I would like to know which is the function or if is useful the diagram. I ask this because when I create a script I don't see the option to create or update diagrams if in this script I add tables or new relationships.

Thanks.

Comment: A diagram _can_ be a useful tool for understanding a database, or fraction thereof.  Since diagrams are "live" they are also convenient for creating database structures.  It is easy to cut and paste groups of columns when creating tables and to create relationships between tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The diagramming features in SQL Server don't help the SQL engine in any way. They are only important if your process (or people) need them. But in my experience, most databases do not have the diagramming components initialized, and diagrams, when needed, are kept external to the database.

Comment: Thanks, it is what I want to know, if it is only interesting for documentation or it was used for something more. Thanks.